# Server responding very slow to PHPMailer gmail SMTP

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I am using this example code provided in PHPMailer. Firstly, the code executes really slow (atleast 1-2 minutes of loading in browser) and then gives me some errors.

```
<?php
/**
* This example shows settings to use when sending via Google's Gmail servers.
*/

//SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
//This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer;

//Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
$mail->isSMTP();

//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages 
// 2 = client and server messages
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

//Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
$mail->Port = 587;

//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = "myGmailId@gmail.com";

//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "myPassword";

//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('myGmailId@gmail.com', 'Andrew Mathew');

//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('myGmailId@gmail.com', 'Andrew Mathew');

//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress('myOtherId@gmail.com', 'John Doe');

//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';

//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));

//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

//Attach an image file
//$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "Message sent!"; 
}
?>
```

Errors I receive is-

SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
SMTP connect() failed.         https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

I have authorized my gmail account to use google's less secure app. Is there any other changes I need to make in my server or in php configuration files to make this work?

P.S. I have not installed anything on my server, I have just downloaded PHPMailer from GitHub and placed it in my working directory.

Comment: Try setting $mail->isHTML(true)

Comment: Didn't work! Same thing's happening. Can it be that my php library is faulty? Should I consider reinstalling apache on my server?

Comment: Can you please paste all the HTML the PHPMailer outputs ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a PHPMailer bug, it's a problem with your server. If you read the troubleshooting docs linked to in the error message (why it's there) it will give you some suggestions to try to figure out what is wrong with your connectivity. It's likely that either DNS lookups are failing or your network is not letting you out.

Setting `SMTPDebug=3` will provide some lower level debug output relating to the connection.